# Use ttf file in overleaf Latex for standard font

Tags: latex

**UPDATE:**
Ok i think a lot of problems are solved now. First I needed to include ttf. Than I had some issues with the headlines. But the last listing will show my solution :D Thank you :D

**(step 1 of 3)**
Hi I want to change my standard font of my overleaf testfile..
The example is strange because I need to write a custom comand before my code.
But I just want to use my ttf as standard everywhere!

```
% 
% Example of how to use a custom TTF font by following the directions here:
% http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php 
%
% In this case, the custom font is LoKinderSchrift, from
% http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Uncategorized/22887/LoKinderSchrift
%
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{custom}{m}{n} #1 }}

\title{Example: Custom Font}
\author{writeLaTeX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Normal Font Text.

\Huge\customfont{Custom Font Text!}

\end{document}
```

**(Step2 of 3)**

Ok thank you I was able to introduce my ttf into my document.

- It looks like the numebr is to small?
- How to delete the point after
  the number at chapter?

[ODD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co0mQ.png)

- The Table of content looks ok.
- How to make Chapter names bold?

[content looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYERu.png)

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % don't use `utf8x`

%\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{custom}{m}{n} #1 }}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{test.ttf}

\title{Example: Custom Font}
\author{writeLaTeX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Testchapter}
How to delete the point before the chapter?

The NUMBER looks smaller than the TEXT ?!
WHY?
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
It
\chapter{Testchapter}
How to delete the point before the chapter?
Why 
this is a chaptertext
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
\section{testsection}
this is a section test
Normal Font Text.
It
\end{document}
```

---

**(step 3 of 3)**
**Final solution:**

```
\documentclass[report]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}

 \usepackage[left=6cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{test.ttf}
\begin {document} 
\tableofcontents 
\blinddocument 
\end {document}
```

Comment: Don't use `utf8x` this will cause a lot of problems once overleaf updates to a newer latex version.

Comment: ok :) you have any idea how I can choose a ttf file in overleaf?

Comment: If you want to use a custom ttf file, I would change the compiler to either `lualatex` or `xelatex` and the  use `fontspec` to change the font

Comment: has lualatex or xelatex disadvantages when I want to write a my thesis? Or is it the same?

Comment: They are a bit slower, but with how fast today's computers are that shouldn't be too much or a problem. If you must use special fonts, I would use lualatex. (But carefully consider if the font you choose is really suitable. Does it have all the characters you might need? Math support? etc.)

Comment: its just from my university... but its not a must have

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to compile your document with xelatex or lualatex. This way, you can use the `fontspec` package and easily use fonts installed on your computer or even just .ttf files:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % don't use `utf8x`

%\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{custom}{m}{n} #1 }}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{lokisd__.ttf}

\title{Example: Custom Font}
\author{writeLaTeX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Normal Font Text.

\Huge Custom Font Text!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot for showing this example :D Maybe it will make a better impression if I use the ttf of my university. So if I still can export to pdf  and no big errors occur I will use it.